# Contract Role or Tier 2 in United Kingdom - UK - Which is easier?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, contracts

I am a Non-EU experienced Software Engineer, and I am planning to move to London for work. I do know that my two options are either Tier 2 or contract roles.

1. For Tier 2: I am a Mid-Senior Software Engineer, and it is "Occupations in Shortage" list. How hard it is to get? Is it relatively easy to get  Blue Card?
2. For Contract: I recently heard from a recruiter that it is easier to have a contract role. Is that correct? Do I need lots of paperwork or establish an Umbrella company for that? Would you provide an official source of information for the contract roles?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Hi Hakan, can you please clarify what you mean when you say "Blue Card"? I'd assume something along the lines of a residence/work permit (judging from the term's use in EU, which the UK has opt out even before the Brexit process)?

Comment: @B.Liu, Thats right, EU BLue card is an EU Employment PErmit and not valid for UK.